# Prevent site directory from being displayed

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a subdomain on which I have put up all the js code for my webiste to interact with another application. For eg: at code.example.com

Whenever, the user types this address,code.example.com, all the contents of the directory are listed. How do I prevent this thing? I do not have nay index.html or index.aspx here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your IIS Configuration, turn off Directory browsing.

If you say what version of IIS you're using, then we can give specific steps on how to turn directory browsing off.